# Post editors are not suggested recipients for @-addressing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, replies

There is no username popup suggesting completion when typing an editor's user name prefix.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Find a post by AUser that was edited by UserB
2. Write a comment addressing `@UserB`

**Expected results:**

When having typed `@U`, the completion popup should suggest `@UserB`

**Actual results:**

No popup, as if there were no such user in the list of addressable users.

> [image]

---

[The Meta post on this feature states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020); while referencing [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him/36055#36055):

> Notifications apply to the author, commenters, and editors of the question or answer that you are commenting on—users not in that list cannot be notified. You can also notify a ♦ moderator who closed the question.

The popup can easily be seen as an indicator whether the user whose name I'm typing will receive my message, since, while typing a user's name and the name disappears from the suggestion list, it means I mistyped and the user will not be notified.

This behavior suggests that editors will not be notified at all, [while they actually are](https://superuser.com/questions/252673/asus-eee-win7-x86-service-pack-1-failure-code-80073701-unknown-error). This is why I classified this as a **bug**.

Comment: For some user names, the popup is a helpful indicator whether I type the name correctly at all: I didn't know that @ldigas' user name starts with a lower case L until I attempted to @-address a comment. `@I` just didn't show the autocompletion.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting myself from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112360/is-the-reply-in-a-comment-to-the-editor-of-a-post-broken/112364#112364):

> The autocompleter only autocompletes actual commentors. We decided to *not* autocomplete editors, because
>
> a) it's a *very* rarely used feature, 
>  b) it'd be quite some work to make this work nice performance-wise, and 
> c) it would probably be more confusing then helpful ("Who the hell is this User12345 and why is he in my autocomplete list?").

Comment: You're already retrieving information about the most recent editor of a post to display that information next to the original author. And he is displayed visibly next to the original author's avatar, with little chance of confusing. Wouldn't it make sense to at least add *that* user to the list, getting 90% of topics and use cases right?