# Why are some names not auto-completed when I try to reply to them?

Tags: discussion, questions

I wanted to comment on something in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/387515/36744). But when I type

```
@si
```

no auto-completion kicks in.

If I type out the users name, the whole `@name` is removed from the posted comment.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Editors can be replied to, as well as the moderator closing a topic (including notifications), but they're never autocompleted. [Related](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3812/22317).

Comment: I'm seeing sinni in your example and Daniel on my answer below for auto-complete, so I'm not sure why you weren't seeing sinni on yours.

Comment: @DMA57361 Now that another user has replied to the answer mentioned above, sinni is autocompleted. This seems to confirm what you've said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only a post's author and one comment are having a conversation then any `@` notifications between them are removed from the start of comments on the grounds they are considered noise because post owners are *always* notified of comments whether you `@` them or not.

This will not happen if any other person is involved in that comment thread.

*(For ref see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97290/147926 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97099/147926 among probably others on MSO)*

For the sake of completeness, I guess I should point to the [**How do comment @ replies work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) FAQ post, in case you want more detailed information in general.

---

As a side note, comments that attempt to ping multiple users (ie, multiple `@`'s) [are also blocked](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-use-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings-in-comments/2615#2615), the work around (backticks) will cause only the first `@` to be notified.

Comment: It's no longer possible to even mention multiple users with the `@`. Trying to do so results in error, even if only one of them is an applicable recipient. Try to reply to this comment @-addressing e.g. Oliver and Ivo.

Comment: The exception is the first comment to a post. It appears to not contain any @ validation, since only one user can ever be notified.

Comment: `@`DanielBeck I've attempted to cover pinging multiple people in the last paragraph, and the 'fix' is to use backticks (which doesn't really fix anything 'cos the @'s then don't work!).

Comment: I seriously must be going blind :-/ Sorry about that.

Comment: After reading a bit more about it, I think my main problem was that I didn't see it as a tool of notification but rather thought it was used to signal to whom parts of a comment are directed.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg that's fair enough, personally I'd also considered it so too original, with the notification being a happy side bonus. But as you can see from the links in my answer there was plenty of resistance to the @-removal/blocking when it was introduced.