# Change request review comments

Tags: discussion, review

I got my first request asking me to approve some proposed changes to an answer I had given to a question.

I found it hard to choose the option "cause damage", but had to, since that was the only one that let me enter a message.  I think it would be great if the message were decoupled from the reason.  What I wanted to select was something like "proposed change does not improve the answer" and give a comment on why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select the "causes harm" option, that phrase doesn't actually appear anywhere permanent. The only thing that will show up on the review verdict page is the custom text you typed in the text box.

To illustrate, I just rejected [this edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/559068) with a custom reason (though "attempt to reply" would have fit just fine):

[image: "causes harm" appears nowhere]

Neither the short title of DavidPostill's rejection reason ("attempt to reply") nor "causes harm" appear.

Comment: That's good to know. At least the reject reason is more private than what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: ok thanks for that.  Haven't been on the receiving end, and didn't want to just upset the proposed editor.

Comment: @Adrien The drawback with this approach is that there is no notification to the editor. He will only see the message if he goes to his profile and looks at his all actions -> suggestions.

Comment: @DavidPostill that sounds like a new feature if ever I saw one

Comment: @DavidPostill There's [kind of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624/295684) an alert when suggested edits are rejected; it appears when the editor goes to edit another post.

Comment: @BenN Ah. OK. I've never had one rejected so I've never seen this :)

Answer (score 2):

#### I wanted to select was something like "proposed change does not improve the answer" and give a comment on why.

You could have chosen:

> no improvement whatsoever
>
> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

And followed up with a comment on your answer addressed to the editor using @editor:

> @editor your proposed edit was rejected because ...

Note:

> Notifications apply to the author, commenters, and **editors** of the question or answer that you are commenting on - users not in that list cannot be notified. You can also notify a ♦ moderator who closed the question.

Source [Post editors are not suggested recipients for @-addressing](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3812/post-editors-are-not-suggested-recipients-for-addressing)

Comment: I did actually consider that, but was reluctant to drag it out into the open like that.  Maybe a new feature could be the ability to send a message to other members in restricted situations like this.

Comment: p.s. thanks for the info on @ addressing, didn't know it took the next step of notifying that user.

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198977/195817), you can @-ping somebody who suggested an edit only if the edit was accepted.

Comment: @Scott Good point.